# Is there a way to add a counter below my traffic light code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

This code displays a traffic light on the turtle.screen(). I'm trying to add a countdown timer in my code which should be displayed on the turtle screen below the traffic light and not on the python terminal.

```
import turtle
import time
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("traffic lights")
wn.bgcolor("black")
#box
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.color("yellow")
pen.width(3)
pen.hideturtle()
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-30, 60)
pen.pendown()
pen.fd(60)
pen.rt(90)
pen.fd(120)
pen.rt(90)
pen.fd(60)
pen.rt(90)
pen.fd(120)

#red
red_light = turtle.Turtle()
red_light.shape("circle")
red_light.color("grey")
red_light.penup()
red_light.goto(0,40)

#yellow
yellow_light= turtle.Turtle()
yellow_light.shape("circle")
yellow_light.color("grey")
yellow_light.penup()
yellow_light.goto(0,0)

#green
green_light= turtle.Turtle()
green_light.shape("circle")
green_light.color("grey")
green_light.penup()
green_light.goto(0,-40)

while True:
    yellow_light.color("grey")
    red_light.color("red")
    time.sleep(4)

    red_light.color("grey")
    green_light.color("green")
    time.sleep(3)

    green_light.color("grey")
    yellow_light.color("yellow")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Where can I add the counter code so that it can be displayed on the turtle screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One difficulty in adding such a feature is that this program is built incorrectly.  Things like `while True:` and `time.sleep(4)` are to be avoided in an event-driven world like turtle.  Instead, consider turtle's own `ontimer()` method which does a better job and plays nicely with events.

First thing to do is fix your code to use a state machine and `ontimer()` to change the lights:

```
def state_machine():
    if red_light.pencolor() == 'red':
        red_light.color('grey')
        green_light.color('green')
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 3000)

    elif green_light.pencolor() == 'green':
        green_light.color('grey')
        yellow_light.color('yellow')
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 2000)

    elif yellow_light.pencolor() == 'yellow':
        yellow_light.color('grey')
        red_light.color('red')
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 4000)
```

For this to work, one of the lights has to start out lit, instead of grey.  Once that's working, we can add a countdown timer as well:

```
def countdown(seconds):
    count.clear()
    count.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)

    seconds -= 1

    if seconds > 0:
        screen.ontimer(lambda s=seconds: countdown(s), 1000)
```

And put it all together:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Traffic Lights")
screen.bgcolor('black')

# box
pen = Turtle(visible=False)
pen.color('yellow')
pen.width(3)
pen.penup()
pen.goto(-30, 60)
pen.pendown()

for _ in range(2):
    pen.fd(60)
    pen.rt(90)
    pen.fd(120)
    pen.rt(90)

# count down timer
count = Turtle(visible=False)
count.color('white')
count.penup()
count.sety(-100)

# red light
red_light = Turtle('circle')
red_light.color('grey')
red_light.penup()
red_light.sety(40)

# yellow light
yellow_light = Turtle('circle')
yellow_light.color('yellow')  # initially on
yellow_light.penup()

# green light
green_light = Turtle('circle')
green_light.color('grey')
green_light.penup()
green_light.sety(-40)

def countdown(seconds):
    count.clear()
    count.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)

    seconds -= 1

    if seconds > 0:
        screen.ontimer(lambda s=seconds: countdown(s), 1000)

def state_machine():
    if red_light.pencolor() == 'red':
        red_light.color('grey')
        green_light.color('green')
        countdown(3)
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 3000)

    elif green_light.pencolor() == 'green':
        green_light.color('grey')
        yellow_light.color('yellow')
        countdown(2)
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 2000)

    elif yellow_light.pencolor() == 'yellow':
        yellow_light.color('grey')
        red_light.color('red')
        countdown(4)
        screen.ontimer(state_machine, 4000)

state_machine()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Another advange of this approach is that when you quit your original code, you typically get ten lines of error messages as the window closing is out of sync with your `sleep()` calls.  In the revised code above, closing the window exits cleanly, with no error messages, as everything is in sync.